# Menubar - using both server and client handlers

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to add both a client handler and server handler to a menu bar item?
Below is the code in which I added a server handler but can't seem to add a 2nd handler.

```
// create menu bar
var menuBar = app.createMenuBar().setWidth(600);


menuBar.addItem('New CA', newCA_handler).addSeparator()
.addItem('Unapproved CA', unapproved_handler).addSeparator()
.addItem('Approved CA', approved_handler).addSeparator()
.addItem('Cap List Detail', capList_handler)
```

If I code menu items this way with setCommand, it replaces first handler

```
var menuItem0 = app.createMenuItem('MenuItem0', handler);
menuItem0.setCommand(test_handler);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is not possible to do that. This seems like a good candidate for an enhancement request on Apps Script [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Also, when searching the tracker to see if there wasn't already an issue opened regarding this, I found other [more critical problem](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1413) regarding menuItems, you may want to *star* it.